# Is there a faster way to pull all my previously single-USE flags into /etc/portage/make.conf?

Tags: gentoo

When I used to emerge my software I was using `USE` instead of adding the flags to my `/etc/portage/make.conf` file. (Example: `sudo USE="djvu postscript synctex magic" emerge --ask app-text/{zathura,zathura-meta}`.

Now whenever I update my system, I have to re-emerge those programs with the previously used USE flags. This tells me I might want to add them to the make.conf file. Is there an easier way to do this than going through each line in my `.{bash,zsh}_history` file?

I recently found out about `euse -a` but I don't know if this is a complete list. If I can use `euse -a` then I can just use bash to put it all into one line and replace my `USE="..."` line in make.conf.

Comment: I decided to pull every USE flag from the last emerge for each program in .{bash,zsh}_history into one document called `~/USES` -- Then I ran `cat USES | xargs -n1 | sort -u | tr '\n' ' ' >> NEWUSES` and moved it into `/etc/portage/make.conf`. It's not exactly the most efficient, but I think it will have to do. I will try to create a workaround for this when/if I can.

I am leaving this open just in case anyone knows a good fix, because I'm sure I'm not the only person who may need this solved.

Answer (score 0):

In /var/db/pkg/*category*/*pkg_name-version*/ you could find several files that could help :

- IUSE_EFFECTIVE: Current flags.
- PKGUSE: Overrided flags (file exists only if needed).

Comment: I looked around in the directory you mentioned. The file "IUSE_EFFECTIVE" appears to have more flags than I have in use, and PKGUSE does not appear to exist. But I found a file called "USE". I used cat and compared it to the USE flags for a random package I have installed. It's almost the same USE flags, but with a few extra that aren't showing up in the emerge list. (Such as "userland_GU" and my kernel arch.) Although, I belive this is in the right direction. This was very useful, thank you.

Comment: Another lead could be in /usr/portage/metadata/md5-cache/category/pkg_name-version. This is odd that you don't have any PKGUSE, i have more than 100 (find /var/db/pkg/ -name "PKGUSE" | wc -l).

Answer (score -1):

`/etc/portage/package.use` is what you need.

https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki//etc/portage/package.use

Comment: I understand what you're talking about, except that it is not what I needed at the time. I was simply looking for how to acquire all of the USE flags that I have used. I use /etc/portage/package.use/, but it's not relevant to the problem. [edited: I hit enter way too early.]